# Email returning number values instead of name

Tags: javascript, php

my code is returning the number of field instead of the name like the brand of the car:

```
<select id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Marca</option>
                       <option value="23">Aprillia</option>
                        <option value="1826">Porsche</option>
                        <option value="4131">Saab</option>
```

I can't figure out why.
My javascript code is:

```
<select id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" <?php if($inputMarcaId == "0"): ?>selected<?php endif; ?>>Marca</option>
                                <?php

                                $arguments = array(
                                    'offset'           => '',
                                    'showposts'        => '-1',
                                    's'                => '',
                                    'category'         => '',
                                    'tag'              => '',
                                    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
                                    'include'          => '',
                                    'exclude'          => '',
                                    'meta_key'         => '',
                                    'meta_value'       => '',
                                    'post_type'        => 'marcas',
                                    'post_mime_type'   => '',
                                    'post_parent'      => '',
                                    'post_status'      => '',
                                    'suppress_filters' => '0'
                                );

                                $marcas = get_posts( $arguments );

                                foreach($marcas as $marca):
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $marca->ID ?>" <?php if($inputAreaId == $marca->ID): ?>selected<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $marca->post_title; ?></option>
                                <?php                                                                                                                                      
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: So what's there in code after the `foreach` line at the end?

Comment: I'm going to edit code with that part

Comment: I've edit the code with that last part.

Comment: When you send something over POST, it's the value, not the text, that gets sent. You can fetch it asynchronously with JS and send it that way. There is no Javascript in this question

Comment: I think i dont know how to do that :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my code is returning the number of field instead of the name like the brand of the car

That's because in PHP you're setting the value attribute of each option to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $marca->ID ?>"
```

If you need the car name there, you should use `$marca->post_title` instead. But be sure to change other parts of the code accordingly. For example, it is being used to pre-select the car in dropdown here:

```
 <?php if($inputAreaId == $marca->ID): ?>selected<?php endif; ?>
```

Having said that, that's just the explanation of what is happening. If you need the car name instead of car ID in the email, you should read the "text" property instead of "value" when you are reading the selected car from dropdown.

Changing the markup to use car name as value might require quite a few changes downstream. So changing the method of reading the dropdown might be preferable.

Comment: Can you give me your email Nisarg? There's something i want to talk with you.
btw i added you on linkedin.

Comment: are your there?

Comment: @JoãoApolinário I won't be able to respond to emails or access linkedIn for a couple of hours. I will get back to you. Btw if you have a programming related question, you can post a new question on stack overflow.